# opposite for .closest() or synonym for it in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have made a table that is changing the href attribute according to which custom radio button is checked. just found a code from stack to check if the checked radio and button are in the same row allow my button to get a data attribute and link.
but i can not code a simple alert for when the `!.closest('tr')` is clicked.
it would be great if someone can help me with it.
actually i was searching for an opposite for `.closest()` in `jQuery` or something same as `.closest()` in `javascript` but have not find anything Comprehensible for my programming knowledge level.
it would be great if someone can solve this with javascript. but i will appreaciate all answers.

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
                        $('[name=radio]').on('click', function() {
                            var link = $(this).data('href')
                            if (($(this).closest('tr').find('.packages-link').prop('href', link))) {
                                $(this).closest('tr').find('.packages-link').prop('href', link)
                            } else {
                                $(x).on('click', function() {
                                    alert('please click on the same row as your package')
                                })
                            }
                        })
                    })
```

```css
  .custom-checkmark {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            height: 18px;
            width: 18px;
            background-color: lightgrey;
            border-radius: 10%;
        }
        
        .table-content-label input:checked~.custom-checkmark {
            background-color: #f5821f;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width:80%;margin:auto;text-align: center;direction: rtl!important;" class="bg-table-blue">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <th style="padding: 15px;margin: 0 5px;text-align: center;background-color: #006ac2;">
                                test
                            </th>
                            <th style="padding: 15px;margin: 0 5px;text-align: center;background-color: #006ac2;">test2</th>
                            <th style="padding: 15px;margin: 0 5px;text-align: center;background-color: #006ac2;">test3</th>
                            <th style="padding: 15px;margin: 0 5px;text-align: center;background-color: #006ac2;">test4</th>

                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="padding: 20px;text-align: center;">
                                name3
                            </td>

                            <td style="padding: 20px;text-align: center;">
                                <div style="display: flex;align-items: center;justify-content: center;">
                                    29,900,000
                                    <label class="table-content-label" style=" display: block;position: relative;padding-left: 25px;margin-bottom: 12px;cursor: pointer;font-size: 15px;-webkit-user-select: none;-moz-user-select: none;-ms-user-select: none;user-select: none; ">
                                        <input style="position: absolute;opacity: 0;cursor: pointer;" name="radio" class="packages-radio" data-href="https://ecare.mabnatelecom.com/services/check-cart-view/1019" type="radio">
                                        <span class="custom-checkmark"></span>
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td style="padding: 20px;text-align: center;">
                                <div style="display: flex;align-items: center;justify-content: center;">
                                    29,900,000
                                    <label class="table-content-label" style=" display: block;position: relative;padding-left: 25px;margin-bottom: 12px;cursor: pointer;font-size: 15px;-webkit-user-select: none;-moz-user-select: none;-ms-user-select: none;user-select: none; ">
                                        <input style="position: absolute;opacity: 0;cursor: pointer;" name="radio" class="packages-radio" data-href="wvcvcw34" type="radio">
                                        <span class="custom-checkmark"></span>
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td style="padding: 20px 0;text-align: center;">
                                <a class="packages-link" style="background-color: #f5821f;text-decoration: none;color: white;padding: 10px 60px;" href="">buy</a>
                            </td>

                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="padding: 20px;text-align: center;">
                                name5
                            </td>
                            <td style="padding: 20px;text-align: center;">
                                <div style="display: flex;align-items: center;justify-content: center;">
                                    28,900,000
                                    <label class="table-content-label" style=" display: block;position: relative;padding-left: 25px;margin-bottom: 12px;cursor: pointer;font-size: 15px;-webkit-user-select: none;-moz-user-select: none;-ms-user-select: none;user-select: none; ">
                                        <input style="position: absolute;opacity: 0;cursor: pointer;" name="radio" class="packages-radio" data-href="ww3434" type="radio">
                                        <span class="custom-checkmark"></span>
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td style="padding: 20px;text-align: center;">
                                <div style="display: flex;align-items: center;justify-content: center;">
                                    28,900,000
                                    <label class="table-content-label" style=" display: block;position: relative;padding-left: 25px;margin-bottom: 12px;cursor: pointer;font-size: 15px;-webkit-user-select: none;-moz-user-select: none;-ms-user-select: none;user-select: none; ">
                                        <input style="position: absolute;opacity: 0;cursor: pointer;" name="radio" class="packages-radio" data-href="ww4" type="radio">
                                        <span class="custom-checkmark"></span>
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td style="padding: 20px 0;text-align: center;">
                                <a class="packages-link" style="background-color: #f5821f;text-decoration: none;color: white;padding: 10px 60px;" href="">buy</a>
                            </td>

                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="padding: 20px;text-align: center;">
                                name2
                            </td>
                            <td style="padding: 20px;text-align: center;">
                                <div style="display: flex;align-items: center;justify-content: center;">
                                    32,900,000
                                    <label class="table-content-label" style=" display: block;position: relative;padding-left: 25px;margin-bottom: 12px;cursor: pointer;font-size: 15px;-webkit-user-select: none;-moz-user-select: none;-ms-user-select: none;user-select: none; ">
                                        <input style="position: absolute;opacity: 0;cursor: pointer;" name="radio" class="packages-radio" data-href="https://ecare.mabnatelecom.com/services/check-cart-view/982" type="radio">
                                        <span class="custom-checkmark"></span>
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td style="padding: 20px;text-align: center;">
                                <div style="display: flex;align-items: center;justify-content: center;">
                                    32,900,000
                                    <label class="table-content-label" style=" display: block;position: relative;padding-left: 25px;margin-bottom: 12px;cursor: pointer;font-size: 15px;-webkit-user-select: none;-moz-user-select: none;-ms-user-select: none;user-select: none; ">
                                        <input style="position: absolute;opacity: 0;cursor: pointer;" name="radio" class="packages-radio" data-href="wgggw34" type="radio">
                                        <span class="custom-checkmark"></span>
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td style="padding: 20px 0;text-align: center;">
                                <a class="packages-link" style="background-color: #f5821f;text-decoration: none;color: white;padding: 10px 60px;" href="">buy</a>
                            </td>

                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="padding: 20px;text-align: center;">
                                name
                            </td>
                            <td style="padding: 20px;text-align: center;">
                                <div style="display: flex;align-items: center;justify-content: center;">
                                    27,490,000
                                    <label class="table-content-label" style=" display: block;position: relative;padding-left: 25px;margin-bottom: 12px;cursor: pointer;font-size: 15px;-webkit-user-select: none;-moz-user-select: none;-ms-user-select: none;user-select: none; ">
                                        <input style="position: absolute;opacity: 0;cursor: pointer;" name="radio" class="packages-radio" data-href="https://ecare.mabnatelecom.com/services/check-cart-view/984" type="radio">
                                        <span class="custom-checkmark"></span>
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td style="padding: 20px;text-align: center;">
                                <div style="display: flex;align-items: center;justify-content: center;">
                                    27,490,000
                                    <label class="table-content-label" style=" display: block;position: relative;padding-left: 25px;margin-bottom: 12px;cursor: pointer;font-size: 15px;-webkit-user-select: none;-moz-user-select: none;-ms-user-select: none;user-select: none; ">
                                        <input style="position: absolute;opacity: 0;cursor: pointer;" name="radio" class="packages-radio" data-href="wgggw34" type="radio">
                                        <span class="custom-checkmark"></span>
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td style="padding: 20px 0;text-align: center;">
                                <a class="packages-link" style="background-color: #f5821f;text-decoration: none;color: white;padding: 10px 60px;" href="">buy</a>
                            </td>

                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "*a simple alert for when the !.closest('tr') is clicked*". Can you elaborate?

Comment: Why don't you put the checkbox label inside the `<label>` element?

Comment: @Bergi sure bergi it was a little hard for me to explain it. as you see we four rows on each row we have a button. the button will link you to a new page if you choose a checkbox in the same row as button you click at last. and as you see it is working fine. but if you choose a checkbox in one line and then click on another lines button it will no do anything actually here i want it to show the user an alert to click on the same chosen package button. i hope i could explane it better

Comment: @Bergi actually that is because in html code we have radio button but i wanted to cutomize it to look like an checkbox. to be honest i used stack previous issues to do that. i have no idea it is correct or not.what is your opinion?

Comment: In that case you should register an event listener on those buttons, and check in that listener whether the radio button in the current row is selected.

Comment: See [this info](https://github.com/nefe/You-Dont-Need-jQuery#1.6)

Comment: @bergi exactly what you said bergi,, i can define whether the radio button in the current row is selected but i can not write a code that define whether the radio button in the current row is not selected

Comment: @PaulT. thanks paul